# Communicate between MDI form and SDI form through event c# windows application

Tags: c#

please some one help with small code for communicate between MDI form and SDI form through event in c#.

Answer (score -1):

according to my knowledge you can communicate between two forms as you communicate with two SDI Forms.
if you need to retrieve a value or something simple operation based on common data types like int, bool, string then i suggest you to use stored value under project setting..
(project properties --> setting --> create a variable to hold your value and set scope to user)

but keep in mind to reset this vale to a pre-defined default value because .net serialize the values.
this can case errors on your project depending on your system.

sorry for not being able to give you a code example because this moment i don't have any editor with me.